# How to access properties from an ID in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a page where I can list all the bookings from an account but encountering a problem. I would like to access all the properties from the room that's assigned to a booking but i'm not quite sure how to achieve this.

Bookings Table:
[image]

Room Model:

```
public class Room
{
    public int RoomID { get; set; }

    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public string RoomType { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int Adults { get; set; }

    public int Childs { get; set; }

    public bool SmokingRoom { get; set; }

    public bool IsOccupied { get; set; }

    public Floor Floor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
 }
```

Booking Model:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfReservation { get; set; }

    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }

    public DateTime Departure { get; set; }

    public int Adults { get; set; }

    public int Children { get; set; }

    public Room Room { get; set; }

    public bool CheckIn { get; set; }

    public bool CheckOut { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    }
```

Databasehandler method:

```
        public static List<Booking> GetAllBookingsByAccount(int id)
        {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();

        var bookings = context.Bookings.Where(b => b.Account.AccountID == id).ToList();

        return bookings;
        }
```

View:

```
    @if (Model.Bookings.Count != 0)
    {
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Arrival</th>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>Hotel</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                    <th>Persons</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var booking in Model.Bookings)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@booking.Arrival.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>@booking.Departure.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@booking.TotalPersons</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@booking.Status</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>You currently do not have any bookings.</p>
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you are using EF and have the Room object as virtual on the Booking object then you should be able to drill down into it.  If not then you'll have to set up a second query.  Can you post your class definitions?

Comment: @nurdyguy I added them in the question

Comment: When you step through using the debugger, are you able to drill down into the Room?  Also, are you using Entity Framework (nm see it in the tags now...)

Comment: Make **Room** a virtual property on the Booking class and you should be able to access it's property through lazy loading

Comment: @nurdyguy I could not drill into the Room as the value was null, the answer below solved that issue and I can succesfully access the room properties now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lazy loading to work you need to set the properties as virtual so that EF is able to override the property. This means you do not have to call the Include method.

Update your data model to:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfReservation { get; set; }

    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }

    public DateTime Departure { get; set; }

    public int Adults { get; set; }

    public int Children { get; set; }

    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }

    public bool CheckIn { get; set; }

    public bool CheckOut { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

That will enable EF to lazyload and you'll be able to access all the properties from that entity without any extra code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the room on bookings:

```
var bookings = context.Bookings.Include("Room").Where(b => b.Account.AccountID == id).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! While debugging the room was null and with this include I can access all the properties now :)